# Exception Unhanded - This was Nullpointer C++

Tags: c++, pointers, nullpointerexception

I have two classes Display and Snake. 
With the Display class I hols some functionality that involves creating buffer and etc. 
I'm trying to do something that seem logical to me but apparently not to the compiler

cSnake.h

```
class Snake 
{
public:
    Snake();
    void printSnake();
    ~Snake();

private:
    Display* display;

};
```

cSnake.cpp

```
Snake::Snake()  {}

void Snake::printSnake() {
    display->PrintCharecter(40, 15, L"    Hello World   ");
}

Snake::~Snake() {}
```

This is the Display class

```
Class Display{
public:
void CreateScreenBuffer();
void DisplayFrame();
void PrintCharecter(int x, int y LPCWSTR text);
private:
int nScreenWidth;
int nScreenHeight;
wchar_t *screen;
}
```

```
// The function that I try to call
void Display::PrintCharecter(int x, int y, LPCWSTR text) {
    wsprintf(&screen[y* nScreenWidth + x], text); // exception is thrown here
}
```

Calling it in the main

```
Snake snake
snake.printSnake();
```

Then it throws unhanded exception that. 
Being NULL pointer. I bit confused here, which one the NULL pointer is it the function call or the array screen?

Comment: Well, what does `display` point to?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: With a better example we will be able to show you how best to avoid this problem and the sundry other problems that result from `Display* display;`

Comment: Well, I updated the question. Maybe know is more clear, where the exception in thrown.

Answer (score 0):

The error is that the Display pointer points to nothing, which is an uninitialized pointer. A pointer only stores the address of the memory, not the actual memory. Therefore you have only created a pointer, but not the memory it points to on the heap. This means that in your constructor, you should create a new display object on the heap and assign that to your pointer.

```
Snake::Snake()
{
    display = new Display;
}
```

This will give you your expected behaviour.
It's also important to note that you must delete the memory the pointer points to otherwise it will just float there until the program ends. Therefore your Snake destructor should `delete` display:

```
Snake::~Snake()
{
    delete display;
}
```

Comment: Better idea: Don't dynamically allocate `display` at all.

Comment: Also note [The Rule of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three).

Comment: Good point, but if you want the same display object to be pointed to by various other  objects, you could instead pass it into the constructor and have many snakes that write to the same the same "display".

Comment: Truth. [`std::shared_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) can be excellent at solving that problem.

Comment: Also, I solved the problem with a pointer because the questioner was using a pointer, if I was going to improve the code I'd have a couple other changes(don't create a Display object called display, etc.) and probably wouldn't use a pointer.

Comment: The `display` pointer is uninitialized. That’s not the same as a null pointer. Still bad, though.